# How to multiply a sqlite db value with unit on load before populate the grid

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have a database with these columns

```
|Name|Quantity|Price|Type|Eta|Language|
|Farmakon|200.1mg|35€|F|2|EN|
|Botron|13g|35€|F|15|ES|
|Botron|10g|31€|F|13|ES|
|Puller|0.50mg|35€|T|1|EN|
|Rovtres|7.2cl|35€|BN|12|UK|
```

I use this Cursor

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(
                        "SELECT Id AS _id, Name, Quantity, Price, FROM mytable "
                                + "WHERE Type LIKE ? AND Eta LIKE ? AND Language LIKE ? ORDER BY Name",
                        new String[] { "%" + type + "%", "%" + eta + "%",
                                "%" + language + "%" });
```

to get the values

```
|Name|Quantity|Price|
|Botron|10g|31€|F|13|ES|
|Botron|13g|35€|
|Farmakon|200.1mg|35€|
|Puller|0.50mg|35€|
|Rovtres|7.2cl|35€|
```

That will be used to populate a Grid

I use this code to populate a grid with a SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
        R.layout.row, c, cols, views);
```

Now I need to multiply the values of the Quantity according the Name,
for example all Quantity of *Botron* rows should be multiplied for *10.1* maintaining the measure unit *g, mg* etc.

Because I have to populate the grid this kind of operation should be done in the Cursor c.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because I have to populate the grid this kind of operation should be
>   done in the Cursor c.

You can't modify the `Cursor` but you could use a simple `ViewBinder` on the adapter to do the extra calculation:

```
    adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor,
                int columnIndex) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.theidOfTheViewWithTheQuantity) {
                // get the quantity from the Cursor, but I don't know how you stored it
                float quantity = cursor.getFloat(columnIndex);
                // get the name
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(the_column_name));
                if (name.equals("Botron" )) {
                    quantity = quantity * 10.0f;
                    ((TextView)view).setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But if the value of Quantity column are text String as "10g", "12.5g" etc... still works or will cause parsing problems??

Comment: @AndreaF It will not work because the  parsing to a float will fail. But your code is not right, you should save those quantities as a numerical value in the database using the lowest unit(for example `mg`). All the values would be saved as `mg` so `10g` would become `10000`(mg) in the database. Then you could easily get them as float and to the multiplication. You could even transform them in code to `g` if you need it.

Comment: I have tried to edit the db to test your method, unfortunately the column *Quantity* shows only *nd* values for all rows(...maybe because doesn't cycle all rows??)

Comment: I have done more test, for some reason the condition if (name.equals("Botron" )) results always false.

Comment: @AndreaF Are you sure you get the name from the right column of the cursor. Print the name variable and see what you get.

Comment: Right, there was a little whitespace... your code is perfect, thanks 10000.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of SQLite supports functions as part of it's queries, so I would suggest extending [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), and performing the multiplication in your `bindView()` method.

Comment: In that way should I extend the CursorAdapter? Could you give me more details?

Comment: Check out http://chetanandroidarora.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/customcursoradapter/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder()` to change the values while they are being loaded from the `cursor` to the `Grid`.

Comment: Could you give me a sample of use?